# If I am filling one column then it automatically fills the rest of the drop down

Tags: reactjs

So, I have started working on ReactJs. So, the issue that I am facing is that when I am choosing one option in one dropdown then that option gets filled in the rest of the drop down menu as well. I want it to be filled only in the column which I want to fill in. How can I stop the value to be filled in the other dropdown menu? Here is my code.

`````
          <div className="cards-wrap row justify-content-md-center">
            <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div className="prescription-form">
                <div className="login-form" style={{ borderRadius: '5px' }}>
                  <div className="pr-login-box">
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <div>
                        <Form.Item label="Start" className="prescription_date">
                          {getFieldDecorator('start', {
                            rules: [
                              {
                                type: 'object',
                                required: true,
                                message: 'Please select date!',
                              },
                            ],
                          })(<DatePicker />)}
                        </Form.Item>

                        <Form.Item label="End" className="prescription_date">
                          {getFieldDecorator('end', {
                            rules: [
                              {
                                type: 'object',
                                required: true,
                                message: 'Please select date!',
                              },
                            ],
                          })(<DatePicker />)}
                        </Form.Item>
                      </div>
                      {this.state.prescriptionItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                          <div className="new-item" key={index}>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="What"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('what', {
                                rules: [
                                  // {
                                  //     required: true,
                                  //     message: 'Please select Medicine!',
                                  // },
                                ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select a option">
                                  <Option value="">Abhayarishtam</Option>
                                  <Option value="">Amritarishtam</Option>
                                  <Option value="">Ashtachurnam</Option>
                                  <Option value="">Brahmi Ghritam</Option>
                                  <Option value="">
                                    Amritotharam Kashayam
                                  </Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="When"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('when', {
                                rules: [
                                  // {
                                  //     required: true,
                                  //     message: 'Please select!',
                                  // },
                                ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select When">
                                  <Option value="morning">Morning</Option>
                                  <Option value="afternoon">Afternoon</Option>
                                  <Option value="evening">Evevning</Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="Quantity"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                              style={{ width: '15%' }}
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('quantity', {
                                rules: [
                                  // {
                                  //     required: true,
                                  //     message: 'Please select!',
                                  // },
                                ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select Quantity">
                                  <Option value="1/2">1/2</Option>
                                  <Option value="1">1</Option>
                                  <Option value="2">2</Option>
                                  <Option value="3">3</Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="Unit"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                              style={{ width: '15%' }}
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('unit', {
                                // rules: [
                                //     {
                                //         required: true,
                                //         message: 'Please select!',
                                //     },
                                // ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select a option">
                                  <Option value="ltr">ltr</Option>
                                  <Option value="grm">grm</Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="How Often"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('often', {
                                // rules: [
                                //     {
                                //         required: true,
                                //         message: 'Please select!',
                                //     },
                                // ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select a option">
                                  <Option value="after_meal">After Meal</Option>
                                  <Option value="before_meal">
                                    Before Meal
                                  </Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item>
                              {getFieldDecorator('notes')(
                                <TextArea rows={3} />,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            {/* <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, index)} value={item}></input> */}
                            <a
                              className="remove"
                              onClick={() => this.handleRemove(index)}
                            >
                              <Icon type="close-circle" />
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        );
                      })}
                      <Button
                        onClick={e => this.addprescriptionItem(e)}
                        className="btn"
                        type="primary"
                      >
                        Add Prescription Item
                      </Button>

                      <Form.Item {...tailFormItemLayout} className="form-btn">
                        <Button
                          className="cl-clone"
                          type="button"
                          htmlType="button"
                        >
                          Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          className="cl-fill btn-h-40 btn-save float-right"
                          type="primary"
                          htmlType="submit"
                        >
                          Save
                        </Button>
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>````
`````

Comment: Are you using state?
Is it possible for you to create working example?

Comment: What do you mean by creating working example?

Comment: For eg. If i choose morning from "Select What" then if i click the button then the next drop down is already filled with morning. I want it to be empty

Comment: Working example means if you can reproduce this on js Fiddle, code sanbox, code pen anywhere i would be able to help you.

In what dropdown there is no item called `morning` are you just giving example? and why all option values of all `what` select are same?

Comment: So, in 'Select When' if i click on morning then if i am adding a drop down then in the select when field morning will be automatically chosen. I will not be able to change it. If i change morning to afternoon then it will change in the value of my drop down as well

Comment: Please replicate this on any online editor. Then i'll be able to help.